# Is it possible to halt execution of javascript for a finite amount of time?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to halt execution of javascript for a finite amount of time? await is the closest thing I came across, but still it does not stop current execution of javascript. I actually tried busy-waiting on a variable, but in that case it was not able to come out of busy-waiting loop. Also I don't even know whether halting/stopping is ever possible in javascript since it is single threaded.

Exact scenario in which I am trying :

```
inside a callback() {
     <make 2 ajax requests, wait for response> 
     <stop for sometime until one of the response is received>
     return <redirect page using response received>
}
```

Note that callback can be called only once, and it should return a redirect url, if no return is given the page actually redirects to default fallback . So I want to stop for sometime to actually wait for events inside this callback.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sleep

Comment: Do you want to execute a part of the script after a period of time? Do you want to debbug the code? What do you want to do?

Comment: You can continuously do *something* until a certain condition is met as long as that condition is met without the need to clear the callstack, thus preventing the code outside of the loop and any callbacks from running until the condition is met. That's basically what you are doing any time you run a for/while loop. Otherwise, no, that's not possible.

Comment: the "condition" can't be based on something that would require a clear callstack, such as an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly achieve it in an async scenario (by simulating it). As you postpone your task to a certain time in the future, when the event loop will pick it up.

#### Async/Await Example:

```js
const sleep = t => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t))


const main = async _ => {
  /*do something*/
  await sleep(3000) //3 seconds
  /*rest of the stuff*/
}
```

#### Promise way:

```js
const sleep = t => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t))

const main = _ => {
  doSometasks().then(_ => sleep(3000)).then(someClosingTasks)
}
```

***Note:** `doSometasks()` must return a promise (`someClosingTasks()` may or may not return a promise)*

Comment: Really @downvoter, where's your SO etiquette? `-1` all the responses without a comment. If you have something meaningful to pitch in by all means, write a comment or answer the question?

Comment: None of them are useful. Your answer for example suggests using async/await, but the question clearly indicates that it isn't a solution because it doesn't actually stop javascript execution.

Comment: Actually you are wrong, async/await as well as generators allow to save state between calls providing possibility to stop execution for a finite amount of time and resume it when needed.

Comment: Probably my interpretation might be bad, but as Kevin B mentioned this was not the solution as it does not actually stop script execution of the caller.

Comment: Well you can't really do that, unless you implement a busy wait (_which will also halt all other threads running in the background_). Or in `node.js` some form of a blocking system call, like `child_process.spawnSync('sleep 3')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create js generator and (re)schedule execution with `setTimeout` until generator completes.

You can use synchronous XHR requests to block execution without busy loop, but in any case condition will not have a chance be changed if js is blocked in your method, so you have to allow execution of microtasks/macrotasks depending on what you really need.